# ITextSharp XMLWorkerHelper Not Working

Tags: pdf, itext, xmlworker

I am trying to convert an HTML page to PDF.  I am trying to utilize the XMLWorker.  I am following various examples I see around the web.  For some reason, however, the XMLWorkerHelper object seems to think that my PDFWriter object is actually an IElementHandler object.  Because of this, it won't compile.  I don't know what is wrong.  Has anyone experienced this? How do I convince the XMLWorkerHelper that my PDFWriter is in fact a PDFWriter?  Here is my code:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Imports iTextSharp.tool.xml


    Dim bytes As Byte()

    Using ms = New MemoryStream
        Using doc = New Document
            Using writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms)

                doc.Open()

                Using msCSS As New MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(CSSstr))
                    Using msHTML As New MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(HTMLstr))

                       'This Doesn't Work...
                       iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, msHTML, msCSS)

                    End Using
                End Using

                doc.Close()

            End Using
        End Using

        bytes = ms.ToArray

    End Using
```

Comment: Which version of iTextSharp are you using? The `ParseXHtml()` method has changed a couple of times over the years. There *is* a `ParseXHtml()` method that expects an `IElementHandler`, but it expects a different number of parameters. At first sight, you are using a method that does exist and that does expect a `PdfWriter`, so my guess is that you're using an old version of XML Worker and iTextSharp.

Comment: I am not sure which version of ITextSharp I am using.  I am using xmlWorker version 5.5.5.  I will try using the latest version of itextsharp and see what happens.

Comment: The version numbers need to be identical. If you're using XML Worker 5.5.5, then your iTextSharp version also needs to be 5.5.5. Maybe that's causing the problem...

Comment: That was it! Thank you!  I have been struggling with this for a couple of days now.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Bruno, I was able to get it working.  As Bruno pointed out, the version numbers of iTextSharp and XMLWorker need to be identical.  I was apparently using an older version if iTextSharp.  I downloaded the latest version and the problem went away.